# get items from listview in setOnItemClickListener android

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new to Android. I have 5 textview at each position in list view, and I need to get the values of each textview when I click at each position. How do I get values from getItemAtPosition();

Please help me.

Comment: How are you populating your ListView? An Adapter?

Comment: i populate it as an adapter i think

Comment: Well, usually with an adapter you pass in a List or array (e.g ArrayAdapter). Use setOnItemClickListener with the ListView and you will get the position passed to the onItemClick() method when a list item is clicked. Just use the position to get the value you passed in from the List or array.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView txtRow = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

String txtValues = txtRow.getText().toString();
```

arg1 or view is parameter of **onItemClick**

Answer (score 0):

you can get benefit from the view of the argument in the your onItemClick to get the clicked view. then get the value by declaring a new textView and let it have the id of the textView then use the getText() method to actually get the text

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String text1Value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId1)).getText().toString();
            String text2Value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId2)).getText().toString();
            String text3Value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId3)).getText().toString();
            String text4Value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId4)).getText().toString();
            String text5Value = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId5)).getText().toString();


        }
    });
```

feel free to ask me if you didn't get the idea. happy programming

Comment: you have to get the position

Comment: no need for position because the `View` argument gets the clicked view  itself without replicating all the strings for each position. so if i pressed the third item (position 2) the view argument will indicate to view of the third item. so all the values will be to the third item

Comment: but this is wht i did and it give me the textviews of the first position

Comment: try to check the clicked item position by showing a toast or logcat. `Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` maybe there is something wrong with your implementation. and please give me a feedback about the values of positions.

Comment: it shoms me the right position but the textview just the the first position one's

Comment: it doesn't make sense, are you using custom layout for your list, or default android layout?

Comment: can you please add a snippet of your code.. how you set the adapter part please

Comment: you can't do findViewById in here because every list view row has the same id

Comment: Ya i figured because you are using the android default ID, but i was curious how are you using 5 textView, while you said you are using the default which has only 1 textView. that is why I asked for your adapter set up. hope you have already figured it out

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the value of the TextView and you don't care about position, then this is proper:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String text1Value = ((TextView) view).getText();


    }
});
```

onClick passes the clicked view as a parameter. Or are you needing this:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);

    String text1Value = ((TextView) lv.getItemAtPosition(position)).getText();
}
```

Comment: i need to get the value of each textview so how to get it one by one

Comment: it depends on the type of adapter you are using, but you can get the adapter from the listview with "getAdapter" (if you aren't already holding a reference to it) then get the size and iterate over the list. That might be a bit vague, but it should get you going in the right direction.